# Python "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code and it doesn't work

```
for i in range(100):
    with open("New Text Document.txt", "a") as f:
        f.append("Q.) \n")
```

It shows "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'" error

I printed the same with this

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    f = open("IT TextBook Ques.txt", 'r')
    f2 = f.read()
    f1 = f"""{f2}
    Q.) \n"""
    f.close()
    f3 = open("IT TextBook Ques.txt", 'w')
    f3.write(f1)
```

But why didn't the first one work

**I am using Python 3.8.7**

Comment: You should use the write method instead of the append method.

Answer (score 3):

Because it indeed does not have any method named `append`.

You can verify this with `dir`:

```
>>> f = open('/tmp/test.yml', 'a')
>>> dir(f) ['_CHUNK_SIZE', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_checkClosed', '_checkReadable', '_checkSeekable', '_checkWritable', '_finalizing', 'buffer', 'close', 'closed', 'detach', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'line_buffering', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'read', 'readable', 'readline', 'readlines', 'reconfigure', 'seek', 'seekable', 'tell', 'truncate', 'writable', 'write', 'write_through', 'writelines']
```

In this case, with `_io.TextIOWrapper`, "append" is the mode in which the file is opened.

The method to call is `write`.

That's why your first example didn't worked but the second one did.

Answer (score 3):

Files don't have an append() method. If you want to append a file, you only open the file in "a" mode and use f.write()
You can also use your second code but it is the long way to do.
So you should use:

```py
for i in range(100):
    f=open("Your Document.txt", 'a')
    f.write("Q.) \n")
    f.close()
```